# Why do we need OpenDDS run_test.pl?

Tags: perl, opendds

I am running OpenDDS MPC based example stockQuoter. I deleted the run_test.pl, still the project builds and runs properly. why do we need this Perl script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need it and you're free to start the programs directly. All examples and tests in OpenDDS have a file called run_test.pl for the purposes of testing. Among other functions, they define what programs get called with what arguments for a certain test scenario and are responsible for killing the programs if they get stuck.